# Save html to a new directory automatically - Rmarkdown

Tags: html, directory, r-markdown, export

I have created a .RMD file that can be used to analyze different data sets. However, I am not able to automate the way to export this data in an html that contains a different name depending on the embedded dataset. For example, if I analyze the data set "Data1.csv", I would like to create a folder called "Data1" and put inside all the files resulting from running the script, and the generated html with the name "Data1.html". But if I then load the "Data2.csv" file, I would like to generate a new folder called "Data2" and a new html (Data2.html) that is saved in the "Data2" folder. Does anyone know if it's possible to do this in rmarkdown?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `rmarkdown::render`? In combination with the concept of parameterized reports (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html) would solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.